# Getting "Qt: Session management error: Could not open network socket" and segmentation fault in Mayavi

Tags: python, qt

With Mayavi in Python 2.7.13 and Ubuntu 17.04 I get

```
>>> import mayavi.mlab
Qt: Session management error: Could not open network socket

>>> mayavi.mlab.text3d(0, 0, 0, 'Hello')
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

On the command-line prompt I get

```
$ mayavi2
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I am using a pip-install version and tried:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall mayavi
sudo pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pyface
```

with `strace mayavi2` the segmentation fault occurs near

```
 open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 15
```

I suspect there is some kind of incompatibility here?

Comment: It may be worth to note that `Qt: Session management error: Could not open network socket` is also output by meshlab, but I have not (yet) experienced a crash with that program.